# Select Distinct rows in a table

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have a Bid entity, a User entity and a Vehicle entity.

Bid contains a link to the Vehicle for which the bid was made as well as the User who made the bid.  It also contains the date on which the bid was made.

I am trying to write a query that says

> Give me all the bids for a particular user for all the vehicles that
>   he has bid on.  But, where the user has made multiple bids for a
>   vehicle only give me the last bid.

In other words each Vehicle should have only one result.

Writing the linq query is proving difficult.  Anyone have any idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'm not being a snob and saying you need to try for yourself first, I'm sure you have. I'm just curious.

Comment: I have tried to do a GroupBy but it didn't work.  i have been trying.

Comment: Do the bids have a timestamp of when they where put in?  What kind of PK do you have, an Identity column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user has an `Id` primary key, something like this should work;

```
int userId = <user id to find>

var bids = db.Bids
    .Where(x => x.User.Id == userId)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Vehicle)
    .Select(x => new {
        vehicle = x.Key, 
        lastbid = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.BidTime).First()
    });

foreach (var bid in bids)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Bid: {0} for vehicle {1}", 
            bid.lastbid, bid.vehicle));
```

(the output requiring a reasonable `ToString()` implementation.